# MaOS 13.5 - Conda converting all channel file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel into intel channel

Tags: macos, conda, intel, macos-ventura

I have installed `Intel oneAPI Toolkits` (`Base` and `HPC`) and I have the following installed packages with "`conda list`" :

```
# conda list
# packages in environment at /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
asn1crypto                1.5.1            py39hecd8cb5_0    file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39h9ed2024_1003    file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel
bzip2                     1.0.8                h23dc21b_9    file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel
c-ares                    1.18.1               hca72f7f_0    file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel
ca-certificates           2022.07.19           hecd8cb5_0    file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel
certifi                   2022.6.15        py39hecd8cb5_0    file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel
cffi                      1.15.1           py39hc55c11b_0    file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel
chardet                   4.0.0           py39hecd8cb5_1003    file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel
common_cmplr_lic_rt       2022.2.0             intel_8682    file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel
conda                     4.11.0           py39haac1dbc_1    file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel
conda-package-handling    1.8.1            py39hca72f7f_0    file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel
cryptography              37.0.1           py39hf6deb26_0    file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel
cython                    0.29.25          py39h5253c43_0    file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel
```

I would like to get the same packages but with `intel` channel appearing instead of `file:///opt/intel/oneapi/conda_channel` .

How could I perform this ?

Comment: Why does it matter? The oneAPI installer bundles the packages and installs them. Seems like a waste to reinstall the exact same packages from their Anaconda Cloud channel.

Answer (score 0):

Could likely get away with running an update with `intel` channel prioritized. Something like:

```bash
conda update --all -p /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest --override-channels -c intel
```